# Deeper meaning and intuition behind $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ having the same values for $x$ and for $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, intuition

I was playing around with the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ and I noticed that $f(x)$ has the same values for $x$ and for $\frac{1}{x}$.

Is there any intuition or deeper meaning behind this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $1/z$ corresponds to a circle inversion, this function is invariant under it.

Comment: @b00nheT Thank you! Where can I read more about that, is that Inversive Geometry? It really looks fascinating!

Comment: It looks more like a coincidence than anything. It works for $f(x) = x^k / (1+x^{2k})$ for any $k$, too. I don't think there's anything deep here.

Comment: You can note that $f(x)=(x+x^{-1})^{-1}$, so it's symmetric of $\{x, x^{-1}\}$.

Comment: Functional equations can be very difficult to solve most generally. Some examples are Babbage's functional equation: $$f(f(x)) = x$$

Cauchy's functional equation: $$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$$ for which there **do [exist nonlinear solutions** which are highly pathological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Existence_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers). Your question corresponds to a functional equation $$f(x) = f(1/x)$$ which I suspect is similarly nontrivial

Comment: This functional equation might be a good way to puzzle Maths students. If $y=f(x)=f(\frac{1}{x})$ it follows(?!) that $x=f^{-1}(y)$ and  $\frac{1}{x}=f^{-1}(y)$, so if we put $g(y)=f^{-1}(y)$, $(g(y))^2=1$. Of course you don't actually say that the domain and range need to be specified carefully!

Comment: An important thing to keep in mind is that some functions just obey certain functional equations because they do. There isn't always an intuition (although in this case, there might be).

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: on the opposite, this equation is very easy. To all pairs $(x,x^{-1})$ you assign an arbitrary value. You can also write $x>0\to f(\log x),x<0\to g(\log-x)$ where $f,g$ are even.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure of what you expect but your function is $\frac1{x+1/x}$.

> The field of rational functions is $\Bbb{C}(x)$ and the field of rational functions invariant under $x\to 1/x$ is $\Bbb{C}(x+1/x)$.

The proof requires a bit of field theory : the field extension $\Bbb{C}(x)/\Bbb{C}(x+1/x)$ is algebraic of degree $2$, this is because $x$ is a root of $$(T-x)(T-1/x)=T^2-(x+1/x)T+1\in \Bbb{C}(x+1/x)[T]$$

Thus there is not field between $\Bbb{C}(x)$ and $\Bbb{C}(x+1/x)$ and the latter has to be the full field of rational functions invariant under $x\to 1/x$.

Answer (score 3):

It is interesting to note the trigonometric significance of this. If $x=\tan\theta$, then
\begin{align*}
\dfrac x{1+x^2}&=\dfrac{\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}\\[5pt]
&=\dfrac12\sin2\theta\\
&=\dfrac12\sin\left\{2\left(\dfrac\pi2-\theta\right)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{\cot\theta}{1+\cot^2\theta}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{\dfrac1x}{1+\left(\dfrac1{x}\right)^2}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

A function is even when for all x, f(-x) = f(x).
Your function is an even function in the multiplicative group of reals

Answer (score 1):

There is no deep meaning, you can create as many such functions as you like.

Let $f(x)$ be an even function and let $g(x):=f(\log x)$. Then $g(x)=g(x^{-1})$.

For example

$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$$ is an even function and corresponds to

$$g(x):=\frac{x+x^{-1}}2=\frac{x^2+1}{2x}$$ with the desired property.

Similarly, you can create functions such that

$$f(-x)=\dfrac1{f(x)}$$ or $$f\left(\dfrac1x\right)=-f(x)$$ or $$f\left(\dfrac1x\right)=\dfrac1{f(x)}$$$$\cdots$$

---

Even better, every function has an *even part*,

$$f_e:=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2,$$ and you draw

$$g(x):=f_e(\log x)=\frac{f(\log x)+f(-\log x)}2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$. Then $g(x) = g(\frac{1}{x})$, because $x + \frac{1}{x}$ = $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{x} + x$.

Your function $f(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{x}{x} \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}} = \frac{x}{x(x + \frac{1}{x})} = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$

So some intuitions or deeper meanings behind this are: addition commutes and a reciprocal of a reciprocal is the original value (inverse of inverse). BTW note that $x\ne0$ for this to work - which we know it is, because we have already $\frac{1}{x}$.